# How can we use Div as a complete button when click it would get active rest other div will be inactive

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

```js
function togbtn10() {
  $("#b1").toggleClass("divbtnbg divbtnbg-blue");
  $("#b3").toggleClass("divbtnbg-blue divbtnbg");
  $("#b2").toggleClass("divbtnbg-blue divbtnbg");



}

function togbtn11() {

  $("#b2").toggleClass("divbtnbg divbtnbg-blue");
  $("#b1").toggleClass("divbtnbg-blue divbtnbg");
  $("#b3").toggleClass("divbtnbg-blue divbtnbg");

}

function togbtn12() {

  $("#b3").toggleClass("divbtnbg divbtnbg-blue");
  $("#b2").toggleClass("divbtnbg-blue divbtnbg");
  $("#b1").toggleClass("divbtnbg-blue divbtnbg");


}
```

```css
.divbtnbg {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgb(130, 130, 130) !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  vertical-align: middle;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: rgb(130, 130, 130) !important;
}

.divbtnbg-blue {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  background-color: #e7f6fe;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgb(130, 130, 130) !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  vertical-align: middle;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: rgb(130, 130, 130) !important;
}

.divbtnbg:hover {
  color: rgb(130, 130, 130) !important;
  background-color: #e7f6fe;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgb(130, 130, 130) !important;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-12">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 divbtnbg" id="b1" onclick="togbtn10()">
      <div class="col-12">Update 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 divbtnbg" id="b2" onclick="togbtn11()">
      <div class="col-12">Update 2 </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 divbtnbg" id="b3" onclick="togbtn12()">
      <div class="col-12">Update 3 </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Hi, Here i am trying to make div as a button and i almost get it but there is one problem.

1. The problem is when click one div it would be selected and rest of the other div will be inactive.
2. While checked one div at that time the background color should also be active color blue.
3. The color should be the same which i used for mouse hover.
4. I try to do using toggled js but this can work for only at one id

   (function togbtn10()
   {
   $("#b1").toggleClass("divbtnbg divbtnbg-blue");)}

   the above js work properly for only one div if i used same for other div it get all selected on click
   Please help on this. Thank you

Comment: To add a note from an accessibility perspective, it is best to use standard tags for these purposes and style them to your needs. It is quite difficult to make divs be accessible, whereas buttons are by default (ignoring other aspects of the page).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I want to tell you that there are no need of three different function to move active class we can do it using a simple script code.

This is the snippet for your problem solution:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.divbtnbg').click(function() {
    $('.divbtnbg').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.divbtnbg {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgb(130, 130, 130) !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  vertical-align: middle;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: rgb(130, 130, 130) !important;
}

.divbtnbg.active,
.divbtnbg:hover {
  color: rgb(130, 130, 130) !important;
  background-color: #e7f6fe;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgb(130, 130, 130) !important;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 divbtnbg" id="b1">
        <div class="col-12">Update 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 divbtnbg" id="b2">
        <div class="col-12">Update 2 </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 divbtnbg" id="b3">
        <div class="col-12">Update 3 </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Comeon you wrote the exatct same thing i did, Well almost

Comment: That why i said almost but mine is less complecated ;)

Comment: Thank you so much it is working fine! Thanks once again

Answer (score 1):

That should be a smal change to be made only

```js
$(".menu > div").click(function(){
  $(".menu > div.selected").removeClass("selected");
  $(this).addClass("selected")
})
```

```css
.divbtnbg {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgb(130, 130, 130) !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  vertical-align: middle;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: rgb(130, 130, 130) !important;
}

.divbtnbg:hover, .selected {
  color: rgb(130, 130, 130) !important;
  background-color: #e7f6fe;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgb(130, 130, 130) !important;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-12">
  <div class="row menu">
    <div class="col-md-4 divbtnbg" id="b1">
      <div class="col-12">Update 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 divbtnbg" id="b2">
      <div class="col-12">Update 2 </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 divbtnbg" id="b3">
      <div class="col-12">Update 3 </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks it is working fine. Thank you so much